# My bluetooth connexion is reading only zeros

Tags: android, bluetooth, inputstream

From my Android phone, I'm trying to read (using Bluetooth) incomming strings from an external GPS device.  I've followed mainly the BluetoothChat example and everything seems to work as expected so far.  My reading thread is executing and I can see variable bytes packets incoming when looping with the following code:

```
Log.d(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytes;
// Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
while (true) 
{
    try 
    {                   
        bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

        // Test...
        String strReadBuf = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);   

       // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
       mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothHandler.MessageType.READ,
            bytes, buffer).sendToTarget();
    } catch (IOException e) {
         Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
         sendErrorMessage(R.string.bt_connection_lost);
         break;
    }
 }
```

The strings I'm supposed to read are text strings (NMEA format) but I'm reading only 0 and -32 bytes in my buffer array.  Any idea why I'm getting this?

Comment: What brand & model is the GPS?

Comment: This is a u-blox LEA-4T GPS chips integration.  We've mounted this into a box that can output logs by bluetooth or USB.  When I connect my box to my pc (by USB), I can see the NMEA strings perfectly.  Also, we're using the Bluetooth connexion extensively from a Windows Mobile program on a PDA, so the hardware integration should not be the problem.  I wonder what can make the program reads the 0 and -32 bytes...

Answer (score 0):

```
Log.d(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytes;
// Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

        // Test...
        //String strReadBuf = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
        //I've changed for
        String strReadBuf = new String(buffer);


       // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
       mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothHandler.MessageType.READ,
            bytes, buffer).sendToTarget();
    } catch (IOException e) {
         Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
         sendErrorMessage(R.string.bt_connection_lost);
         break;
    }
 }
```

I used the String constructor `String(byte[])`, where `byte[]` is the buffer deprecating the `byte[]` size. I've used many times and that works for me even if the buffer size changes over time.